# Unit testing with AWS Cognito and GraphQL

Tags: django, graphql, pytest, amazon-cognito

I'm currently writing tests for my software but got stuck at the point.
I try to get data from my db with a normal GraphQL Query but my endpoint is first checking, if the idToken within the header is valid.
For the user handling I'm using AWS Cognito but couldn't find a good way to mock the login to retrieve the valid token to query and mutate the data within various endpoints.

Any idea how to handle this case?

Here is my code from the graphene docs (https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/testing/):

```
# Create a fixture using the graphql_query helper and `client` fixture from `pytest-django`.
import json
import pytest
from graphene_django.utils.testing import graphql_query

# https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/testing/


@pytest.fixture
def client_query(client):
  def func(*args, **kwargs):
    return graphql_query(*args, **kwargs, client=client)

  return func

# Test you query using the client_query fixture
def test_some_query(client_query):
   response = client_query(
    '''
    query GetAllProjectConfig{
    getAllProjectConfig{
        project{
            id
            slug
            name
        }
        config{
            id
        }
    }
    }
    ''',
)

content = json.loads(response.content)
assert 'errors' not in content
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was not so hard:

```
auth_data = {'USERNAME': username, 'PASSWORD': password}

# auth the user on cognito

def auth_cognito_user():
  provider_client = boto3.client(
    'cognito-idp', region_name=os.environ.get('region_name'))
  resp = provider_client.admin_initiate_auth(
    UserPoolId=userpool_id, AuthFlow='ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH', AuthParameters=auth_data, ClientId=client_id)
  # print("RESPONSE COGNITO", resp['AuthenticationResult']['IdToken'])
  return resp['AuthenticationResult']['IdToken']
```